# How to save a number variable to file in applescript?

Tags: variables, applescript, read-write

I am trying to make a simple counter that adds one to the count every time the script is run.  I have tried using a property but that doesn't work because it resets whenever the script is edited or the computer is turned off.  Here is the code I have that I took from [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/9299/applescript-to-spit-out-incremented-number-with-leading-zeros).

```
    set theFile to ":Users:hardware:Library:Scripts:Applications:LightSpeed:" & "CurrentProductCode.txt"

open for access theFile
set fileContents to read theFile
close access theFile

set counter to fileContents as integer

on add_leading_zeros(counter, max_leading_zeros)
    set the threshold_number to (10 ^ max_leading_zeros) as integer
    if counter is less than the threshold_number then
        set the leading_zeros to ""
        set the digit_count to the length of ((counter div 1) as string)
        set the character_count to (max_leading_zeros + 1) - digit_count
        repeat character_count times
            set the leading_zeros to (the leading_zeros & "0") as string
        end repeat
        return (leading_zeros & (counter as text)) as string
    else
        return counter as text
    end if
end add_leading_zeros

add_leading_zeros(counter, 6)


open for access newFile with write permission
set eof of newFile to 0
write counter + 1 to newFile
close access newFile
```

With this I get the error:

> Can’t make ":Users:hardware:Library:Scripts:Applications:LightSpeed:CurrentProductCode.txt" into type file.

If I add "set theFile to theFile as alias" after the first "open for access theFile" it gets a little further in the code, but gets another error:

> Can’t make "1776" into type integer.

And now I am out of ideas.  I have googled all over the place haven't found anything that works for me. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I like to use script objects to store data:

```
set thePath to (path to desktop as text) & "myData.scpt"

script theData
    property Counter : missing value
end script

try
    set theData to load script file thePath
on error
    -- On first run, set the initial value of the variable
    set theData's Counter to 0
end try

--Increment the variable by 1
set theData's Counter to (theData's Counter) + 1

-- save your changes
store script theData in file thePath replacing yes
return theData's Counter
```

Comment: Awesome! Thanks. Works perfectly.  I knew there had to be a better way to store a numeric variable! thanks again